# How to encode and decode docx file using base64 in python

Tags: python, base64, decode, encode, python-docx

I am trying to encode docx file and decode/pass it on frontend/UI in streamlit. As of now i knew how to encode/decode strings using base64 but not with docx file.

If any of you guys have any code on how to achieve it. Please do share here.

```
import base64
import streamlit as st

data = open('/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit-practice/content/A0/A0.02-vocab.docx', 'rb').read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)

st.download_button('Download Here', decoded)
```

I used the above code but not getting the desired result.
Instead I got collection of .xml file. As shown in the below screenshot
[image: result i got from above code]

The supposed decoded document should look like this..
[image: original document snapshot]

If you guys need the docx file that i am trying to encode/decode, here is the link https://docs.google.com/document/d/10zkg1HLDHhZNh83i2tbJqBVMfIsdqW-3/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `filename` argument to `download_button` function

```
import base64
import streamlit as st

data = open("test.docx", "rb").read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)

st.download_button('Download Here', decoded, "decoded_file.docx")
```

Comment: I used it and i am getting collection of xml files after decoding. I have updated the result on my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @lungsang could you share your docx file? Or one piece of it

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10zkg1HLDHhZNh83i2tbJqBVMfIsdqW-3/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106219787963227195154&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @ AnhPC03 Can you download the docx file from above link and try :)

Comment: @lungsang I've updated my answer, take a look to it

Comment: Thank you @AnhPC03 its working fine after adding the filename argument to download_button. Have a great day ahead :)

Comment: I tried marking the answer as useful but it says i needed minimum of 15 reputation. :)

Comment: @lungsang Ok, I got it

Answer (score 0):

This is just encoding You Have to Decode

```
with open('YOUR DATA FILE', 'rb') as binary_file:
    binary_file_data = binary_file.read()
    base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_file_data)
    base64_message = base64_encoded_data.decode('utf-8')
    
    print(base64_message)
```

open the file using open('Your Data file', 'rb'). Note how we passed the 'rb' argument along with the file path - this tells Python that we are reading a binary file. **Without using 'rb'**, Python would assume we are reading a **text file.**

use the read() method to get all the data in the file into the binary_file_data variable. Similar to how we treated strings, we Base64 encoded the bytes with base64.b64encode and then used the decode('utf-8') on base64_encoded_data to get the Base64 encoded data using human-readable characters.

Executing the code will produce similar output to:

```
python3 encoding_binary.py
```

Comment: I am only getting .txt file as result here.